# How to convert array to object that has child as next array item on javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array like
`[ {a: 1}, {b:2}, {c:3} ]`

I want to convert this array to an object like:

`{ a: 1, child: {b: 2, child: { c: 3 } } }`

That's the question.

Comment: I assume `b` needs to be `2` and not `1` in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ES5 can help you with sleek Array prototype methods:

```
[{a:1}, {b:1}, {c:1}, {d:1}].reduceRight(function(child, parent) {
    parent.child = child;
    return parent;
});
```

This will do the work.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the array, keeping a reference to a root object and moving a second reference down as you generate child objects

```
(function (arr) {
    var i, j, o = {}, e = o;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        e = e.child = {};
        for (j in arr[i]) if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(arr, j)) {
            e[j] = arr[i][j];
            break;
        }
    }
    return o.child;
}([{a: 1}, {b:2}, {c:3}])); // {a: 1, child: {b: 2, child: {c: 3 }}}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Breaking down the problem and understanding what is required**.

Lets denote `o` as Object and dissect the following as:

```
(1). {                               
  2.    "a": 1,                       
(3).    "child": {                      
  4.               "b"    : 1,              
(5).               "child": { 
  6.                           "c": 3 
  7.                        }  
  8.             } 
  9. }
```

(1) an object that contains two properties:

- a:1, child: o{ }

(3) child: o{ }, an object that contains two properties:

- b:1, child: o{ }

(5) child: o{ }, an object that contains one property:

- c:3

**So, given;**

```
[ {a: 1}, {b:2}, {c:3} ]
```

**you can do the following:**

```
var o = { a:1, child { } };   // (1)
o.child = { b:2, child{ } };  // (3)
o.child.child = { c: 3 };     // (5)
```

**Of course, this is just to illustrate for understanding.**

The solution to the above is to loop through each `Object`, for every value, create an `Object` and set the property name as key, again value as `Object`... repeat until `n`.

With [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org), you may utilize `_.map()` as the following:

```
_.map({one: 1, two: 2, three: 3}, function(num, key) { 
      return num * 3; 
});
=> [3, 6, 9]
```

Hope this helps.